# Apparmor denies ntpd access to its own logs

Tags: logging, ntpd, apparmor

ntpd complains that it cannot access its own logs

```
# ntpd -qgddd 
...
11 Sep 16:23:00 ntpd[7262]: can't open /var/log/ntpstats/peerstats.20130911: Permission denied
...
11 Sep 16:23:01 ntpd[7262]: can't open /var/log/ntpstats/peerstats.20130911: Permission denied
...
11 Sep 16:23:01 ntpd[7262]: can't open /var/log/ntpstats/loopstats.20130911: Permission denied
```

and strace agrees

```
open("/var/log/ntpstats/loopstats.20130911", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

According to syslog apparmor blocks it from doing that

```
[526597.819210] type=1400 audit(1378909374.692:91): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1013 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/usr/local/sbin/" pid=7262 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[526597.819277] type=1400 audit(1378909374.692:92): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1013 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/usr/local/bin/" pid=7262 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[526597.819330] type=1400 audit(1378909374.692:93): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1013 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/usr/sbin/" pid=7262 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[526597.819383] type=1400 audit(1378909374.692:94): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1013 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/usr/bin/" pid=7262 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[526597.819434] type=1400 audit(1378909374.692:95): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1013 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/sbin/" pid=7262 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[526597.819485] type=1400 audit(1378909374.692:96): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1013 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/bin/" pid=7262 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[526597.819541] type=1400 audit(1378909374.692:97): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1013 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/usr/bin/" pid=7262 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

even though it's clearly allowed in ntp's profile

```
# less /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd
...
/var/log/ntpstats/clockstats* rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/loopstats*  rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/peerstats*  rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/rawstats*   rwl,
/var/log/ntpstats/sysstats*   rwl,
```

So what's going on?

It's an Ubuntu Server 13.04 with 3.8.0-30-generic kernel.

Answer (score 1):

That apparmor log shows that ntpd tries to access (read) directories like `/usr/local/sbin/`, `/usr/sbin/ etc`. It doesn't tell anything about `ntpd` being denied access to `/var/log/ntpstats`.

Please check regular unix permissions on /`var/log/ntpstats` and its contents.